# Solr managed_schema with embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, solr

I am using Solr 6.6.0 and mongo-connector 2.5.1

I'm trying to get the following shape into solr

```
{
  "firstName": "test",
  "lastName": "test",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "address": "123 test ln",
      "city": "St. Louis",
      "state": "MO"
    }
  ]
}
```

Setting the field as multivalued did nothing, and I've read this document https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers

Nothing seems to cover what the managed schema file should look like. All the information I can find seems to be on the theory of how it works, not an example of it working. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into the answer. I added a dynamic field of "*" and all the address fields populated in the format of "addresses.0.fieldName".

Now I'm using a dynamicField of "addresses.*" and everything seems to be working.